# What are the types of natural disasters?

Tags: natural-disasters

I want to ask in a broader and clearer sense. What would you say are the types of natural disasters because it gets a bit confusing by reading from online data.

1. By researching a lot - I have found are total 6 types:
   -> Geophysical , meteorological , hydrological , biological , climatological , extraterrestrial , space ,

Like under :

- geophysical would come - volcanic eruptions , earthquakes.
- hydrological you can say comes - Tsunamis , floods , droughts etc

So like that….

Now , I couldn’t like find all of them under a single section of page , book etc. So , am not sure if this is how we classify natural disasters and their types correctly. That’s why I want to learn and know exactly how do we classify them. How the tree of classification of their types are done.

Thank you

Comment: You say you "know that".  Might want to give your source for being told that.  As for me it seems a bit of a manufactured categorization, one that others may setup many different ways.  It's not (as far as I know) some standardized categorization.

Comment: please try to narrow down this question a bit,as it is now it is very broad.please take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_disaster to see some of the problems in your question.

Comment: Using trond hansen's link, it seems S.M.T. is asking about "natural hazards"  instead of "natural disasters".  I don't know if your categories cover them all (e.g. what about wildfire?). The FEMA list has: avalanche, coastal flooding, cold wave, drought, earthquake, hail, heat wave, hurricane (tropical cyclone), ice storm, landslide, lightning, riverine flooding, strong wind, tornado, tsunami, volcanic activity, wildfire, winter weather, tornados, and dust storms.  Looks like the FEMA list doesn't include pandemics or meteor impact but I think they are also "natural hazards" as you've noted.